# Is there is a way to pass in a value for a Razor textbox?

Tags: asp.net, razor, asp.net-mvc

This seems like a simple question but I can't find a good Razor resource that explains how to do this.

I have a simple text box with a value. Let say

```
<input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" value="RE" />
```

How can I create a textbox like this one in Razor with a default value?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Replacing "RE" with a razor value? `value='@someVariable'`

Comment: If your value is populated from a model - [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337520/prepopulate-html-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337520/prepopulate-html-textboxfor-in-asp-net-mvc-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at this SO post: [have razor text box default value disappear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8433234/have-razor-text-box-default-value-disappear).  There, the poster has provided a glimpse of how he/she provided a value for a textbox.

Another link: [Text box default value in Razor syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6668018/text-box-default-value-in-razor-syntax).

Shame on you for not looking this up :D

Comment: I tried the first link and (behold) it doesn't work in IE so I can't use it. I will try the second option and see if it works. Thanks btw